# What are the Best Practices in Creating Animation to be used in a LibGDX Game?

Tags: android, animation, libgdx

I've just learned about the capabilities of libGDX in terms of animation. I know how to use the texture packer,read atlases to be used animation, and use the animation class.

I use Adobe Flash to create animations and export them into PNG sequences then use the texture packer. But it fails when there are too many images to be converted. I tested it by using 80 images(600X600). I was trying to rotate a big magic circle.

My question is, what are the other methods to create animation? What is the best way to create PNG Sequences?

EDIT: I used the TexturePacker-Gui: 
http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/2012/06/texturepacker-gui-support-for-multiple-packs/
and was able to pack my sprites into an atlas..Clicking 'Pack Selected' instead of 'Pack Em All' did the trick (maybe a bug for the program). And rotating that magic circle by sprite animation was a big mistake. The only question that remains is if there is any better way to create animation other than using Flash?

Answer (score 0):

I have some tool form create spritesheet.

I didnt use this one 
[libgdx-texturepacker-gui](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-texturepacker-gui/), maybe you can try.

I am using this [Texture Packer](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just rotate something you don't need animation. You can create a `Sprite` using only one image and then do something like `sprite.rotate(...);`

Comment: Haha big mistake of mine... Realized it after posting this question. Going to try that thanks =)